# How to get data from database in listbox using List<> in as.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, listbox

I am new in MVC, I have search on many site for fetching data from database and display in Listbox but I did’nt get any proper answer, in Every site there is hardcoded example for listbox just like this.

```
public List<Product> allProducts = new List<Product>
{
new Product(1, "Games Console", "Fun for all the family", 199.99m),
new Product(2, "MP3 player", "Listen to your favourite tunes on the move", 99.99m),
new Product(3, "Smart Phone", "Apps, apps, apps", 399.99m),
new Product(4, "Digital Photo frame", "All your photos in one beautiful frame", 49.99m),
new Product(5, "E-book reader", "Take your favourite books on the move with you", 149.99m),
new Product(6, "DVD Box Set", "All of season one plus exclusive extras", 39.99m)
};
```

But I want to display data from database just like this;

```
public List<Model> allModels = new List<Model>
{
//Query to fetch data from database
};
```

I am not getting how to write the query in List, Please tell me how to write query inside the above syntax……

Please help me….

**UPDATED**

Actually I wanted to display the two list box one that contain the data from db and 2ndlistbox contains the selected item from 1stlistbox,
My code is like this…

Model:

```
public class Model
    {
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Class { get; set; }
    }
```

In that I have added some data in database

ViewModels Class:

```
public class ViewModel
    {
public List<Model> AvailableModel { get; set; }
public List<Model> RequestedModel { get; set; }

public int[] AvailableSelected { get; set; }
public int[] RequestedSelected { get; set; }

public string SavedRequested { get; set; }
    }
```

I am Following this Articals:
[[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136730/ASP-NET-MVC-Basics-Working-with-ListBoxes][1]](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136730/ASP-NET-MVC-Basics-Working-with-ListBoxes%5d%5b1%5d)

As your suggested code:

```
var data = (from m indb.Models
selectm.Name);

List<Model>modellist = data.ToList();
```

I have write this and 
it throws An error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DemoListBox.Models.Model>'
```

Comment: What db are you using? are you using entity framework?

Comment: i m using entity framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
YourEntity db = new YourEntity();

var data = (from m in db.Models
             select m.Name);

List<string> list = data.ToList<string>();
```

Comment: After Applying this, it showing this error **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DemoListBox.Models.Model>'**

Comment: @Uriel_SVK Try :List<SomeClassForYourData> list = data.ToList<DemoListBox.Models.Model>();

Comment: yeah... that "someClassForYourData" was just an example cause i dont know names of your classes... just change it to anything you need...

Comment: select m.Name is resulting to string, so result of that ToList is List<string> not List<model>, change List<model> to List<string>

Comment: there is two errors **Error 2 'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments**                                                                                                                             
**Error 1 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<DemoListBox.Models.Model>'**

Comment: @Uriel_SVK can u suggest me anything about (display the two list box one that contain the data from db and 2nd listbox contains the selected item from 1st listbox)

Comment: you can put items in listbox using `listbox.Items = data`, second list can show data depending on selection in the first one - `SelectionChanged` event or something like that

Answer (score 0):

```
return (from c in db.Product
                     where c.ProductId == ProductId
                     select c).ToList();
```

You just need to add **.ToList()** to return List

Comment: I don't want example on SelectList or SelectListItem, can u tell me about List<>